# openpyxl - default a template column to be text

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to build a data-entry template to distribute to users.  Some of these columns will have the possible values of ("true", "false", "unknown"), so I would like Excel to treat these columns as text instead of Boolean, even if the users only enter the values of "true" or "false" into them.  I don't know up front how many rows any particular user will be entering, so looping through the whole sheet with

```
template_ws.cell(row_number, column_number).number_format = "@"
```

is not practical because I'd have to do it for all 1048576 potential rows.

If I was doing this in Excel, I'd click on the column letter and then change the format from "General" to "Text".  Is there a programmatic way to do this with openpyxl without having to format each individual cell?

Comment: Read [applying-styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#applying-styles)

Comment: I already have, which is where I got the information on applying the style to each cell.  I'd been hoping that I'd either missed something or had misinterpreted what I read.

Comment: There is a `'Normal'` style which should be used for all Cells, where **not** manually is assigned a style, but didn't get it to work.